# How to toggle the side menu bar in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a new app. I have created the side menu. But side menu drawer not working if i am in the same screen.For example in the screenshot i am already in the home screen. Now if i click the home in the side menu there is no action. One more question now the side menu covers the whole screen height. I want to be display between the header and bottom tab navigator. Please help me [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjspS.jpg)

```js
const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator( {
    Home: HomeScreen,
 WebMenu: WebMenuScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {    
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
   labelStyle: {
  fontSize: 15
   },
   tabStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  showIcon: false
   
    },
  });

//MenuDrawer
export class MenuDrawer extends React.Component {

gotoHome = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
}

gotoWebMenu = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('WebMenu');
}

gotoSettings = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings');
}

  render() {
      return(
       <View style = {styles.container}>        
        <Text onPress={this.gotoHome} style = {styles.item} ><Ionicons name="md-home" size={20} />  Home</Text>
        <Text onPress={this.gotoWebMenu} style = {styles.item} ><Ionicons name="logo-rss" size={20} />  Web Menu</Text>
        <Text onPress={this.gotoSettings} style = {styles.item} ><Ionicons name="md-settings" size={20} />  Settings</Text>
      </View>
      )
  }
 
}

//side menu 
const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
  Menu: {
    screen: DashboardTabNavigator,
  },
}, 
 { 
 contentComponent: MenuDrawer,    
 drawerPosition: 'right',
 drawerWidth:width - width/2
 },
  {
  initialRouteName: 'Login'
});


//screen route
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({

  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  Home:{ screen: MyApp},
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
   headerMode: 'null'
});


 
const MyApp1 = createAppContainer(LoginStack);
```

Comment: Can you please share Drawer content component file

Comment: hi @bk7 thanks for your reply. i have added the codes. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    //Props to open/close the drawer
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          <Image
            source={require('../Img/hamburger.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 20, tintColor: '#ffffff' }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And then use it in this way

```
const HomeActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  Home: {
    screen: Main,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Dashboard',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800'
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff'
    }),
  },
}, {headerLayoutPreset: 'center'});
```

Comment: thank you for ur response. i tried but still not working